# How can I implement a notification system in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

I have to send a Firebase Cloud Message (FCM) to an android application when a new post is inserted in a wordpress blog, I already put my code in the wp_includes\post.php , but this will not work, cause of the future WP update(post.php will be replaced and I can't insert my code evry time), so I have to put my code(it works no problem in this) in another place.. where I can put my file?? I have to write a plugin? It's possible to write a plugin that override a function? in this case wp_insert_post? And if this is possible where i retrieve the post data to send via FCM? Can you make an example or link a good example of code if this is possible?

Now my code is inside the wp_insert_post function and so it's executed when you push the button "publish" in new post area.

Comment: You would want to create a plug-in and then probably hook it in to the function in core, not override it.

Answer (score 3):

If you look through the definition of `wp_insert_post()`, you'll see

```
do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );
```

at the end of it. So you can hook into this and perform whatever task you want to after creating a post.

Something like this in your theme's `functions.php` or in your plugin file:

```
do_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'send_notification');
function send_notification($post_ID, $post, $update){
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: This looks like a suitable solution, but I wouldn't put this into the theme's `functions.php` file... a change in the active theme and you will lose the functionality. Plus this functionality has nothing to do with the design of the website so it should **not** go into your theme files.  Rather create a plugin, it's really easy to do, you just need a php file with the proper header and then put that file into your `wp-content/plugins` folder. Try to look at the *hello dolly* plugin for the required header.